# Prestashop 1.6.0.7 Discount Bug

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'm setting an ecommerce with Prestashop 1.6.0.7 and i'm facing this issue:
When i set a product price and then i apply a fixed discount (for example 10€), it show me the correct price on the homepage but when i open product page, it show me a different price.

**For example:**
    Product price = 75,00€
    Discount = 10,00€
    Total on homepage = 65,00
    Total on product page = 65,01 (with 9,99€ of discount)

http://www.atuttocampo.com/home/114-mizuno-wave-twister-3-.html

Answer (score 0):

You can see here the post on Prestashop Forum: 
http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/350394-solved-fix-inside-ps-1609-wrong-rounded-value-using-combinations/

and here you can find the fix:
http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFI-6693